# FOS_USER and changepassword ( if php is not 5.3.6?) in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

sooo basically Im trying to change the password of my users using FOS_USER and symphony.

the code goes as follows (it's the same code as the one on ChangePasswordAction in the FOS_User symphony bundle but the response has been changed to use AJAX

```
   public function changePasswordAction(Request $request) {
   // $form = $this->createForm(new ChangePasswordFormType('Bandness\BandeeBundle\Entity\Bandee'), $this->getUser());

    $user = $this->getUser();

    $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    $formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.change_password.form.factory');

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) { 
            /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
            $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, new Response()));

            return new JsonResponse($this->get('translator')->trans('Bandee.config.changepass.success'),200);
        }
        else return new JsonResponse($this->getTranslatedErrors($form), 422);
    }
```

the thing is that this doesn't seem to be working. when in an apache2 with php 5.3.6 it works perfectly, however on other machines it just doesnt work. the reply it normally gives is "not a valid number" , which doesn't make sense because it shouldn't check a number at all...

i feel there is a bug in FOS_User and some versions of PHP
it's not working on PHP Version 5.4.4 neither on 5.3.10

any suggestions?

Comment: I doubt very much that this is related to a specific version of PHP. Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: how could I debug this? I see everything is so masked that the process is complex. I'd like to make the program like stop at each iteration. but i have no idea of how to do that in symfony, even though I use the app_dev.php